# Dictionary removes first pair

Tags: python

I'm working on implementing a search algorithm. I'm still green when it comes to python, but my problem struck me as very weird. I create a dict containing the links. When I then print out the dict, the first pair is removed. This is also the case for the rest of the code, and it therefore fails.

```
links = {'A': 'B', 'A': 'C', 'D': 'A',  'E': 'A'}
print links
```

That is all the code that is called at the start of the program. It's literally the second and third call made, and it's still weird.

Comment: Dictionaries can only store unique keys.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I did not think of that. Thank you for commenting that though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through [this](http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/)
it will give you better idea about dic, list and Tuples and your above code is not working because you try to store values for same key where dic. needs to have unique keys or it will override

like this

```
A = {'A':'1','A':'2','B':'3'}
```

here A key is not unique so it will be override while in below mention code it will not

```
A = {'A1':'1', 'A2':'2', 'A3':'3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an other approach to store data if you have a key multiple times.

You can use a list of list, but this will not allow you to use all the nice dict features:

```
links = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'A'],  ['E', 'A']]
```

Alternatively you can use a list as the value.

```
links = {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'D': ['A'],  'E': ['A']}
```

If you generate the dict dynamically, the defaultdict is helpful, it initializes the value for a key, for example with a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
links = defaultdict(list)
links['A'].append('B')
links['A'].append('C')
```